# Copy cells containing data (not formulas) and do not have other cells with formulas change

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with a data entry table, and a bunch of formulas that use the data in the data entry table to calculate aggregated outputs. When a user enters data into the data entry tables, and then cuts and pastes data within data entry tables to rearrange the data, the formulas referencing the data entry table change. For example, if C1 contains "=A1" and the user enters 10 into A1, cuts A1 and pastes to A2, then C1 changes to "=A2". How can I make it so the formula in C1 does NOT change? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [indirect](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

```
c1: =indirect("A1")
```

When you cut or drag a cell, you are moving all references to that cell. You can copy the value elsewhere and delete the original, or just try the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Indirect is volatile and will become slow if there are lots of them (I only learned this recently and used to use it all the time before), possibly this??

```
=INDEX($1:$1048576,1,1)
```

Where 1,1 is the reference to row 1, column 1 (ie A1)

Comment: This works, thank you! I need to change several formulas to use this method of referencing cells, and then copy each formula to hundreds of rows. The method of defining the row, column reference in the example here is not treated like a "relative" reference (e.g. if the example formula above is in C1 and you copy it to C2, then A1 is still referenced). I found a work around (=INDEX($1:$1000, CELL("row", A14), 1) that allows me to copy the formula and the row reference to change, but if there is a more elegant/simplier/higher performance solution, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!